# Изменить стандартный URL wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Всем доброго дня, возникла задача сократить URL /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php например на /ajax, достаточно сделать как алиас через .htaccess

Пробовал сам сделать, не работает. Помогите кто может пожалуйста

Comment: Внимание, помогаю: не ищи приключений на седалище.

Comment: @SeVlad это наверное смешная шутка, но я её не понял(

Comment: Это вовсе не шутка, а ценная рекомендация. Совет на всю жизнь.